# How to import Objective-C in Swift framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i create a swift framework, and create a objectivC file in the framework project.

swiftClass.swift:

```
Public swiftClass{
   func test(){
     var c = objectivCClass(); 
   }
}
```

objectivCClass.h:

```
@Interface objectivCClass{
}

@end
```

I know make objectivCClass.h to public header in `Build Phases` , and import it in swiftFramework.h , the framework can works ok.

But I do not make objectivCClass public in `Build Phases` and do not want user knows the class. If I make objectivCClass.h to project/private header , An error happen.
[image]
Who know how to handle it?

Comment: I must say that 'some error happen' is not the most precise description of the problem I saw on SO. Perhaps you could reconsider how much details you want to give us?